Duplicated WP Multisite for testing environment is redirecting to production site
My goal is to have a test.example.de testing environment for my www.example.de WP Blog.
Sadly, the site is still redirecting me to the production-site.
My subdomain is registered as a CNAME with a TTL of 3600 (INVX).
I also added it to my domains on my server-hosting dashboard (UBERSPACE).
Here are all of the steps I made:

Copied html directory (whole production-site) to my local disk

Created a new directory called dev.example.de (note that my hosting provider uberspace is handling subdomains like that, so no need for setting up a vhost. I've also tested it with a simple index.html before I continued and it worked well).

Copied the whole site back to the server via SFTP into the new directory

Changed DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE to my new subdomain URL (test.example.de) inside the wp-config.php file.

Added the following lines inside the wp-config.php file:



    /*  URL for Subdomain */

    define('WP_HOME','http:/\/test.example.de');
    define('WP_SITEURL','http:/\/test.example.de');



Added allow repair:

    a /* Allow repair */
    define('WP\_ALLOW\_REPAIR', true);



Copied the database of my production site in phpMyAdmin and changed the URL in
wp_blogs and wp_site to the subdomain URL. The wp_blogs in the production site database looks like that:

domain: www.example.de
path: /
The wp_blogs in the testing site database looks like that now:
domain: test.example.de
path: / (I also tried pointing to the directory (/user/test.example.de/), but it didn't work either)


Changed DB_Name to the new database name inside the wp-config.php file.

Note: Before I made changes to the wp_blogs, I wasn't being redirected, but it said: Connection to database failed. I can reproduce this 301 error code if I just use the wp-blogs entry form the production database.
The site has also not been updated in a few months. Same for plugins. I wanted to do all that in the testing environment first, to see if there will be issues and to avoid downtime of the blog.
